# Split words with mixed delimeter on comma using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Please, I have a string with mixed delimiters of comma and space : **"J,bolt H Higgs"**
What regex could be used to split them in comma into:

**option a.**

```
    J
    bolt
    H
    Higgs
```

**option b.**

```
J
bolt
H Higgs
```

Thanks

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: (?<=\s|^)(.+?)(?=\s|$)
This will only select H Higgs and not J bolt. Reason is I am finding it difficult to come up with a regex that takes care of the J,bolts.

Comment: if you guys are just going to be down voting without any reasons, then I think that is unfair. You don't just down vote and keep quite. Why are you down voting?

Comment: your question shows no effort

Comment: @DanielA.White, thanks. I honestly don't think that is why. I added the regex I have and explained what it does, except that is not what I am looking for. I won't be asking if I have not tried something, even though it is wrong. So, let the stack overflow experts keep at it. I already got my question solved though.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by

```
\W+
```

for option `A`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/28

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
var string = "J,bolt H Higgs".replace(/[,\s]/g, "\n");
```

Will replace each comma or space character with a newline, which you can then use anywhere.

**Alternative:**

```
var string = "J,bolt H Higgs".split(/[,\s]/g); // returns an array
```

Comment: Please, did you read the part I insisted this must be in regex? What I meant is I don't want the replace or split methods. Just pure regex. Thanks

Comment: @helpdesk `/[,\s]/g` *is* a regex. You can just take that if you want.